# ffmpeg - how to "set" continuity counters when generating .ts segments for HLS live streaming?

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg2-ts

Say I have a batch of 40 JPEGs that represent 2 FPS video, and I want to generate a `m3u8` playlist + h264 `ts` segments for an HLS live stream - so I do something like this:

```
ffmpeg -y -framerate 2 -start_number 0 -i /frames/frame_%d.jpg -frames:v 40 \
       -c:v libx264 -crf 21 -preset veryfast -g 2 \
       -f hls -hls_time 4 -hls_list_size 5 -hls_flags omit_endlist \
       -start_number 0 -segment_start_number 0 -segment_list_flags +live video/stream.m3u8
```

and it gives me a playlist like this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:4
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:4.000000,
stream0.ts
#EXTINF:4.000000,
stream1.ts
#EXTINF:4.000000,
stream2.ts
#EXTINF:4.000000,
stream3.ts
#EXTINF:4.000000,
stream4.ts
```

Great. Now say I get another batch of 40 JPEGS that follows the first, and I want to drop `stream0.ts` (the first 4 seconds / 8 frames of the original 40 JPEGS), and add a new `stream5.ts` (the first 4 seconds / 8 frames of the next 40 JPEGS):

```
ffmpeg -y -framerate 2 -start_number 8 -i /frames/frame_%d.jpg -frames:v 40 \
       -c:v libx264 -crf 21 -preset veryfast -g 2 \
       -f hls -hls_time 4 -hls_list_size 5 -hls_flags omit_endlist \
       -start_number 1 -segment_start_number 1 -segment_list_flags live video/stream.m3u8
```

Then I get this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:4
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXTINF:4.000000,
stream1.ts
#EXTINF:4.000000,
stream2.ts
#EXTINF:4.000000,
stream3.ts
#EXTINF:4.000000,
stream4.ts
#EXTINF:4.000000,
stream5.ts
```

Great. But when I try to play the HLS stream with something like HLS.js or video.js, my video stream stalls out. And when I inspect the stream with `TSLemurs HLS Checker tool`, it warns me about "CC" errors, which I assume means continuity counter errors:

[image]

How can I fix these continuity counter errors? Is there anyway to do this at all with ffmpeg?

Comment: Not implemented. Consider opening a ticket at trac.ffmpeg.org - although search first, I think there's already one.

Comment: Thanks @Gyan. Bummer - but, it seems like if I include a #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tag between each segment, I avoid the continuity counter errors in my HLS stream. So I think that will be my approach for now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `-hls_flags discont_start` for prevent CC errors